# How to replicate a SMTP incoming mail on JAVA args

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am trying to locally debug a remote issue where a java jar is processing an incoming mail:

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/processmail.jar $*
```

I have the code within my eclipse and want to pass the email to it. Is there a way to capture the mail, such as in a logfile, or in a file and pass it to my Java project?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Effectively there is the possibility, you need to have a main(String[] args) function into your main class in the jar, then the args that you pass in the command line after :

java -jar /usr/local/bin/processmail.jar oneemail@onedomain.com, otheremail@otherdomain.com

Here oneemail@onedomain.com and otheremail@otherdomain.com will be passed to the body of main method as part of args variable to be processed, of course you have to manage the implementation of the main method as you need for your intentions, something like:

```
... main(String[] args) {
        doSomething(args[0]);
        doSomething(args[1]);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Just in case... to declare a class as Main in the jar you need use the Manifest file, you may take a look: http://www.coderanch.com/t/383756/java/java/define-main-class-jar